Preserving simple-connectedness under intersection complexes
Given a simplicial complex $X$, and a family of its subcomplexes $\{U_i\}_{i\in I}$, we define the corresponding intersection complex to be the simplicial complex $X_U$ with vertex set $I$ where $A \subseteq I$ form a cell whenever $\bigcap_{i\in A} U_i \neq \emptyset$. If in addition $\{U_i\}_{i\in I}$ covers $X$, i.e. if $\bigcup_{i\in I} = X$, and each $U_i$ is connected, we call $X_U$ a cover complex of $X$.
The question is:

If $X$ is a (finite) simply connected simplicial complex, must each
cover complex of $X$  also be simply connected?

Here is an incomplete proof sketch. The case where $X$ is homeomorphic to the unit disc in the plane is easier (proof?). Let $C= v_0 v_1 \ldots v_k=v_0$ be a cycle in the 1-skeleton of $X_U$. We can restrict our attention to the case where $C$ is induced, i.e. no edge of $X_U$ connects vertices at distance at least two along $C$, because those cycles generate $\pi_1(X_U)$. Notice that such a cycle gives rise to a cycle $C’$ in $X$, obtained by uniting paths between $v_{i-1} \cap v_{i}$ and $v_i \cap v_{1+1}$ for each $i$. Since $X$ is simply connected, there exists a continuous map $F: D^2 \to X$ such that $F$  restricted to $\mathbb{S}^1$ traverses $C’$. If $F$ is bijective, we can reduce to the case where $X$ is homeomorphic to the unit disc mentioned above. If not, I hope that the disc case can be generalised…
Example: The answer is positive when $X$ is a tree. In this case $X_U$ must be a flag complex, i.e. every $k$ clique of the 1-skeleton $G_U$ of $X_U$ spans a $k$-cell. Moreover, it is known that $G_U$ is a chordal graph, which implies that the triangles of $G_U$ generate $\pi(G_U)$. Since  $X_U$ is flag, each triangle of $G_U$ spans a homeomorph of a disc, and it easily follows that $X_U$ is simply connected.
Remarks on notation: The term intersection complex is standard, but cover complex is made up. Has it been studied under a different name?
If we replace cover complex by intersection complex in the question the answer is easily no, as we can remove vertices to create holes.

Yes.
There is a map $X\to X_U$, taking each point $x$ to some point in the simplex corresponding to the set of all $i$ such that $x\in U_i$.
This map induces a surjection $\pi_1(X)\to \pi_1(X_U)$. To see this, take any loop in $X_U$. It can be taken to be an edge path running through vertices $i_0,i_1,\dots , i_k=i_0$. Lift this to a loop in $X$ by sending each $i_j$ to some point $p_j\in U_{i_j}$, sending the midpoint of $[i_j,i_{j+1}]$ to some point $q_j\in U_{i_j}\cap U_{i_{j+1}}$, sending the left half of the interval $[i_j,i_{j+1}]$ to a path in $U_{i_j}$ from $p_j$ to $q_j$, and sending the right half to a path in $U_{i_{j+1}}$ from $q_j$ to $p_{j+1}$.

Tom, one must assume each set $U_i$ is path connected, as is used in your argument. Otherwise, the simplest counterexample is $X = [0,5]$ and $U = {A, B, C}$ with $A = [0,1] \cup [3, 4]$, $B = [1,2]\cup [4, 5]$, and $C = [2, 3]$, so $X_U$ is a circle. This is all in line with what one expects from Björner's version of the Nerve Theorem https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0097316503000153. Björner doesn't explicitly mention the surjection we need here, but it falls out of his proof.

Maybe it's worth noting that one can adjust the definition of the intersection complex, aka nerve, to allow disconnected pieces. I learned this from Fernández-Minian's paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.07235, and the relevant version of the Nerve Theorem is the main result in my paper https://arxiv.org/abs/2305.04794 (with $n=0$). This is surely overkill when one just wants to know about surjectivity on the fundamental group.

(Now I see the OP did put connectedness into the definition of a cover complex.)

@TomGoodwillie: in order for your map to be well-defined, you need to prove that any two homotopic loops in $X$ are mapped to homotopic loops in $X_U$. Can you prove this?

@Agelos: You can make a definite map $X\to X_U$ by letting $X'$ be the barycentric subdivision of $X$, sending each vertex of $X'$ (the barycenter of a simplex of $X$) to the barycenter of the set of all $i$ such that that simplex is contained in $U_i$, and extending linearly over each simplex of $X'$.

Let me just mention an example where $X=S^3$ and $\pi_2(X_U)\neq 0$. Just take a nice cover of $S^2$ (e.g. one whose cover complex is also $S^2$) and pull it back along the Hopf-map to a cover of $S^3$.
